# How can I get three TextView values?

Tags: android, listview, textview

My listview has three textview and one checkbox in horizontal order.

My `listview xml` code

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="5" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="5" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

and `MainActivity.java` code

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                View view, int position, long id) {

            Object vo = (Object)adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);  
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(vo));
        }
    });
```

The log output for `String.valueOf(vo)` is

```
sn.studyroom.ListViewItem@f085546
```

How can I get each of the three `Textview` values?

Comment: can you write full code of the adapter here? we need to see how you pass the list data to ListView

Comment: welcome here, you need to check this first - http://amitandroid.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-listview-with-checkbox-and.html

Comment: Values of the textview came from the data you passed to it. And here 'vo' is tread as a common Object. You may probably cast it into ListViewItem, and the get data from the item you defined.

Comment: just write this code -> ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position) ;

                Log.d(TAG,item.getName());
                Log.d(TAG,item.getNumber());
                Log.d(TAG,item.getTime());

Answer (score 1):

If you catch the clicked object right, you must convert it to `TextView`, and then get your `TextView`'s text like this:

```
String vo = ((TextView)adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getText().toString();
Log.d(TAG, vo);
```

OR

Go your adapter class and create an interface to get clicked item's values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adapter for accessing your text fields and check box. Pass your list to a adapter like this:

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter (context, yourList);
        yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create an adapter like this.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<ListObject> yourList;


    public CustomListAdapter (Context context, List<ListObject> yourList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.yourList= yourList;
    }

    public void refreshAdapter(List<ListObject> yourList){
        this.yourList= yourList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;
        CheckBox checkBox1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return yourList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return yourList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_adapter_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textView1= convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textView2= convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textView3= convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.checkBox1= convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
       //TODO: you can do whatever you want to do here


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrive list data then i want to know about to set data. Are you set model and add in adapter or taking static string arraylist? so let me know then i will suggest better way to do that.